# Setting column names in a newly merged dataframe from multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following list in R, which contains multiple dataframes that have a common column (Date)

```
data <- list(structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(4, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(7, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(10, 11, 12
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

I am trying to merge all of the dataframes in the list into one dataframe using `reduce` and `full_join`, however I'm struggling to figure out how to automatically set all of the column names in the newly merged dataframe as the names of each dataframe that were in the list (so i.e to set the last three column names in the merged dataframe as a, b, c without having to specify them manually). Is there a way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = 'Date')

 Date Value.x Value.y Value
1    1       4       7    10
2    2       5       8    11
3    3       6       9    12
```

Comment: From *"as the names of each dataframe that were in the list"*, it seems that the example data should be a named list, no?

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather go with `list_rbind()` and `pivot_wider()` here:

```r
data <- list(structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(4, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L)), 
             structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(7, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L)), 
             structure(list(Date = c(1, 2, 3), Value = c(10, 11, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))

data |>
  setNames(LETTERS[1:3]) |>
  purrr::list_rbind(names_to = "name") |>
  # by default pivot_wider uses `name` column for names_from
  tidyr::pivot_wider(values_from = Value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    Date     A     B     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     4     7    10
#> 2     2     5     8    11
#> 3     3     6     9    12
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

imap(data, \(x, idx) rename_with(x, ~ str_c(.x, "_", letters[idx]), "Value")) %>% 
  reduce(left_join)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
   Date Value_a Value_b Value_c
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       4       7      10
2     2       5       8      11
3     3       6       9      12
```